# Tilemill label and Shield are overlapping, how can this be solved?

Tags: tilemill

I am trying to use tilemill labels and Shield together for my road designing. But there is a problem with that. Please see the following image for better understanding. The shield is ovarlapping the Road name.

[image]

I used the following code for my .mss

```
#road::Labels {
      text-name: [ROAD_NAME];
      text-face-name: "Candara Bold";
      text-size: 16;
      text-fill: #000000;
      text-placement: line; 
      text-halo-fill: #f6f3f3;
      text-halo-radius: 1;
      text-spacing: 400;
      }
    #road::N_Shield {
        [ROAD_TYPE =1]{
        shield-file:  url("C:\wamp\www\shield.png");
        shield-name: [ROAD_NO];
        shield-face-name:"Arial Bold";
        shield-size:16;
        shield-fill: black;
        shield-line-spacing:5;
        shield-min-distance:1;
        shield-allow-overlap:true;
        shield-placement:line;
        shield-dx:150;
        shield-spacing:450;
        }
     }
```

Anyone can help me what to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try to vary your `shield-spacing` and `text-spacing` values. In other words make them different. This may help the placement of shields occur in a different place in the line than the text.

But a more robust solution is to use `text-label-position-tolerance` and `shield-label-position-tolerance` along with `text-allow-overlap:false` and `shield-allow-overlap:false`. This basically says to Mapnik: "Don't allow labels and shields to overlap but rather try moving them farther along the line until there is room to place them". You can see an example of this in the blog post about upcoming Mapnik features here: http://mapnik.org/news/2012/10/06/gsoc2012-status9/. In short, Mapnik 3.x will support both of these features but Mapnik 2.x only supports `text-label-position-tolerance`.

Comment: Much love, brother. I also used `text-avoid-edges: true;` which helped solve my problems.

Answer (score 2):

Try to put shield-allow-overlap:false to avoid overlapping, it should solve your problem.

Comment: Probably you did not understand it. I know overlap false will banish the symbol. But I want to to all the shield and text annotation